# Django urls.py Regex Not Working Like I Expected

Tags: regex, django, django-views, django-urls

I want to have a URL like these --

```
/chart/2012
/chart/2009
/chart/1996
```

...each #, is a year. So I added this line into my app's urls.py --

```
url(r'^chart/(?P<year>\d+)$',views.chart,name="chart"),
```

but it turns in a 404 when I go to the URL's. Shouldn't the `\d+` capture the digits into the `year` variable?

(and yes, I do have a chart function defined in my views.py & it works when I don't try to use a variable with it)

UPDATE:

Here's the full urls.py --

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns,url
from musichart import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
    url(r'^chart/(?P<year>\d+)$',views.chart,name="chart"),
)
```

Here's my views.py --

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader #Context
from musichart.models import Station,Song,Album,Related,Artist


def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('chart/index.htm')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'title': "Here is the title",
        'testvar': "blah blah blah testing 1 2 3",
        'numero': 17,
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))


def chart(request, year):
    template = loader.get_template('chart/chart.htm')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'title': "Here is the title",
        'testvar': "blah blah blah testing 1 2 3",
        'numero': 17,
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

As you can see, it's bare bones at the moment and just sort of testing to make sure things go through before I go any further. And the 404 page says --

```
Using the URLconf defined in msite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^accounts/
^chart/ ^$ [name='index']
^chart/ ^chart/(?P<year>\d+)$ [name='chart']
^health/
The current URL, chart/2010, didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: does the `chart` function take a `year` parameter?

Comment: Even if it didn't, he wouldn't get a 404 error, as a 404 indicates a mismatch of the URL.

Comment: The 404 gives a list of urls that could be matched along with the actual URL.  Could you post the actual URL as reported by the 404 page?

Comment: Can you show the usage in the template ?

Comment: Can you show also the full urls definitions?

Comment: Ok, I updated the question to show my full urls.py & views.py. I don't think the template stuff will help, 'cause this is definitely a URL problem. The template works fine for the index and it's basically the same as the chart template at this point.

Comment: Please post the traceback from the debug 404 page as suggested by @MikePelley

Comment: There is no traceback, so I'm sure it's not a Python error. There's  just a 404 error. Which leads me to think it must be something about the URL Regex. I've never done much regex before, so I'm pretty lost about what could be wrong with this. I basically used the same Regex that's presented in Django's basic tutorial.

Comment: @Zamphatta If there's no debug 404 page, I'd assume you don't have `DEBUG = True` in your settings.py.  If that's right, could you enable debug and then post the debug 404 page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you're including the "chart" URI component already in the project-level (IE, root) urlconf, so including it again the app's urlconf is throwing off the resolver. Basically try removing the "chart/" from the chart url, like so:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns,url
from musichart import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d+)$',views.chart,name="chart"),
)
```

And in addition, double check that you don't have a trailing space after "chart" when including the app-level urlconf from the root urlconf.

Comment: Oh my goodness, I can't believe that I didn't catch that. I was so caught up in thinking it must've been a regex mistake 'cause I've never really done that before, that I totally missed the real issue. Thanks!!